# Xpages: Refresh one component of an Xpage from another

Tags: javascript, xpages

The layout in my app has a menu on the left and content on the right. When a user selects a menu item on the left I open the correct Xpage. This is pretty standard.

I have transitioned to a Bootstrap menu on the left. Once loaded, state changes (menu selection, accordion drop downs) are handled via CSJS. So this gives me the opportunity (if possible) to refresh the content window on the right without having to submit the whole xpage again.

But I do not think you can do a partial refresh from one custom control to another.

Is there any way to do this or anyway to structure the app so I can do this?

Comment: There's also the dynamic content control.  I think that's intended for this kind of "single page application" you're trying to do.  Personally I almost always take the page update.  My users aren't in really low bandwidth countries and the page refresh isn't a hit they've ever complained about and it also does make developing and maintaining cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do something with postMessage in CSJS. I have used it to do actions, like resize in a XPages when it is embedded inside a widget in IBM Connections. See the interaction in the OpenNTF project 'Generic HTML and XPages Widgets for IBM Connections', https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/blog.xsp?permaLink=NHEF-8YRN3J

More details how to use postMessage. https://davidwalsh.name/window-postmessage

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to wrap your right side contents with a panel and give that panel an id. Then when the user changes something on the left menus do a partial refresh of the panel. You might need to type in the panel id as it will not be available on the id picker in partial refresh.

Howard